# Mockito vc JMockit and Dependency injetion

Tags: java, dependency-injection, mockito, jmockit

I found this article quite interesting http://www.jayway.com/2012/02/25/mockito-and-dependency-injection/ it says that Mockito supports dependency injection by using constructor arguments, setter methods and field injection. I was wondering if JMockit does the same, so far I haven't find no one using JMockit and dependency injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMockit supports dependency injection via arguments and properties. The test class must contain one or more mock properties or mock parameters declared to be @Injectable. The business object you would like to test need to be declared with the annotation @Tested. The @Tested annotation automatically creates an instance of the class and injecting the mocked dependencies.

```
public class SomeTest {
   @Tested CodeUnderTest tested;
   @Injectable Dependency dep1;
   @Injectable AnotherDependency dep2;
   @Injectable int someIntegralProperty = 123;

   @Test
   public void someTestMethod(@Injectable("true") boolean flag, @Injectable("Mary") String name)
   {
      // Record expectations on mocked types, if needed.

      tested.exerciseCodeUnderTest();

      // Verify expectations on mocked types, if required.
   }
}
```

You can find more detailed information here:
http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#tested (official docs)